# xamarin: difference between Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread and MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread

Tags: c#, xamarin

I create a same custom controls, in some of them I use Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread but in but sometimes it throws an error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object

this error occurs when immediately after reading `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`, but if I replace it with `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` works ok.

The section code if this:

```
public class EntryRoundPassword : RelativeLayout
    {
             public EntryRoundPassword() : base()
            {
                  // throws an error
                  Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                  {
                      ......
                  });

                   //works ok
                   MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                   {
                      .....
                   }); 
            }
    }
```

What is the difference between them, because one throws an error and the other does not ?

Comment: FWIW: This is unusual. First time I've heard of a situation where the two behaved differently.

Answer (score 7):

`MainThread` is part of `Essentials`, and is the newer implementation.  The `Device` implementation will eventually be deprecated.  If you want to know the specific implementation differences, you can check the [source code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms)

Comment: thanks, I did not know the existence of MainThread 
until a few days ago, and the Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread would be deprecated

Comment: @luciano cba Xamarin.Forms has a method called `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(Action)` that does the same thing as `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(Action)`. While you can use either method in a Xamarin.Forms app, consider whether or not the calling code has any other need for a dependency on Xamarin.Forms. If not, `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(Action)` is likely a better option.