# Xamarin forms Binding Not updating inside Async task and working fine in Non async

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, async-await, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to Laod a List in async manner. But whenever I'm trying to load in async without Task.Wait() result not showing up even I'm raising OnPropertyChanged event as well (even though its an ObservableCollection) but no effect. If I'm loading it without async its working fine. I almost tried all the resources we have over stack overflow and on Microsoft forum but not able to get a solution.

I will share all the approaches I have tried up to now:

1. I am using Loaded event of ListView and by using EventToCommandBehaviour I am converting that into AsyncCommand so I don't have to use async void.

ViewModelCode:

```
public class FilteredPackagesPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Datum> states;
    private string unitPriceWithDiscount;
    public string UnitPriceWithoutDiscount
    {
        get => unitPriceWithDiscount?? string.Empty;
        set { unitPriceWithDiscount = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(UnitPriceWithoutDiscount)); }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Datum> States
    {
        get { return states; }
        set { SetProperty(ref states, value); }
    }

    public IAsyncCommand<int> FavouriteCommand { get; set; }
    public TaskLoaderNotifier<ObservableCollection<Datum>> Loader { get; }
    public IAsyncCommand<int> PackageDetailCommand { get; set; }
    public AsyncCommand LoadDetailCommand { get; set; }

    public FilteredPackagesPageViewModel()
    {
        FavouriteCommand = new AsyncCommand<int>((arg) => OnLoginClicked(arg));
        PackageDetailCommand = new AsyncCommand<int>((id) => PackageDetailCommandAction(id));
        LoadDetailCommand = new AsyncCommand(LoadPageDetail);
        //States = DataService.GetStates();
    }

    private async Task LoadPageDetail()
    {
        var test = await DataService.GetStates();
        var test1 = new ObservableCollection<Datum>();
        foreach(var state in test)
        {
            test1.Add(state);
        }
        States = test1;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(States));
    }
```

2. I have tried to call this On Appearing as well in code behind but still no effect List Item source not updating at all.
3. I have tried to Initailase an async constructor and called it from calling page still no effect.
4. Working Code: (But not a good approach still UI being blocked)

```
public FilteredPackagesPageViewModel()
        {
            FavouriteCommand = new AsyncCommand<int>((arg) => OnLoginClicked(arg));
            PackageDetailCommand = new AsyncCommand<int>((id) => PackageDetailCommandAction(id));
            LoadTourPackages();
        }

        public async void LoadTourPackages()
        {
            Task.Run(async () => await LoadToursAsync()).Wait();
        }
        public async Task LoadToursAsync()
        {
            States = await DataService.GetStates();
        }
```

5. I have tried to use BeginInvokeOnMainThread() to but that also didn't work.

[image]

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2022, Xamarin forms - 5.0.0

If there is any better, solution please let me know. If there is some issue from my side please let me know that too.

View :

Note : There can't be Binding issue as binding working perfectly whenever I'm running that code synchronously or not awaiting population of ObservalbleCollection.

```
 <Grid BackgroundColor="white">
            <Grid RowDefinitions="20,Auto" RowSpacing="15" Padding="8">
                <syncfusion:SfListView x:Name="listView" 
                                           ItemSize="310" 
                                           Grid.Row="1"
                                           ItemSpacing="0,10,0,5"
                                           ItemsSource="{Binding States,Mode=OneWay}">
                    <syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <viewcell:PackageOverviewViewCell 
                                        ImageUrl="{Binding tourImage,Mode=OneWay}"
                                        Price="{Binding UnitPriceAfterDiscount,Mode=OneWay}" 
                                        Day="{Binding day,Mode=OneWay}"
                                        TourStartdate="{Binding tourStartdate,Mode=OneWay}"
                                        TourEndDate="{Binding tourEnddate,Mode=OneWay}"
                                        Night="{Binding night,Mode=OneWay}"
                                        Duration="{Binding duration,Mode=OneWay}"
                                        tourPackageId="{Binding tourPackageId,Mode=OneWay}"
                                        name="{Binding name,Mode=OneWay}"
                                        PackageDetailCommand="{Binding Path=BindingContext.PackageDetailCommand, Source={x:Reference filtered},Mode=TwoWay}"
                                        PackageDetailCommandParameter="{Binding tourPackageId}"
                                        FavoriteCommand="{Binding Path=BindingContext.FavouriteCommand, Source={x:Reference filtered},Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <syncfusion:SfListView.Behaviors>
                        <extensions:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Loaded" Command="{Binding LoadDetailCommand}"/>
                    </syncfusion:SfListView.Behaviors>
                </syncfusion:SfListView>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @FreakyAli for your suggestion but for some reason  Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread not working but after doing some research I got the solution for that problem as MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread:

```
public void LoadTourPackages()
{
    States = new ObservableCollection<Datum>();
    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( async () =>
    {
        await LoadToursAsync();
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(States));
    });
}

public async Task LoadToursAsync()
{
       try
       {
           States = await DataService.GetStates();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           await GeneralTask.ShowMessageAsync(this.GetType().Name, ex);
       }
}
```

we can find more details on below threads:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/main-thread [xamarin: difference between Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread and MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62154462/ddg#62154530) and according to few resources Its better to use later **MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread** over **Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread**

Answer (score 1):

Your Async method should look like this:

```
 private async Task LoadPageDetail()
 {
    var test = await DataService.GetStates();
    var test1 = new ObservableCollection<Datum>();
    foreach(var state in test)
    {
        test1.Add(state);
    }
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => States = test1);
 }
```

In async methods, you are usually on a background thread and they don't make changes to the UI; to make UI changes always invoke the main thread in async methods.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I have already tried that approach but it doesn't work, I have mentioned in my tried approaches as well. I will add one picture of that too.

Comment: @PrashantRajput And you are sure you are assigning the new value to States and not states

Comment: Yes, I am sure bro. I was assigning new values to public property only (States) for testing purpose I have assigned new values to private property also (states) then tried to Trigger property Changed that also didn't work.

Comment: That's weird, where are you using this collection in your UI?

Comment: I am binding that in my sync fusion listView inside a Content Page, I have view given code in description, you can check that too.